# How do I set the default file save location of an Office document to be the same folder as the template's folder?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-office-2010

I have a series of Microsoft Office 2010 templates (Excel, PowerPoint and Word) **spread through a pre-defined folder hierarchy.**

I need to make sure that when a new document is created from one of those templates, **it defaults to saving it in the same folder as the template it was created from.**

I was able to accomplish the task for Word using a macro such as

```
Sub AutoNew()
   ChangeFileOpenDirectory ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.Path
End Sub
```

but I had no success in replicating this behavior in Excel nor PowerPoint.

Answer (score 1):

Templates are quite different in Excel and Word from what I can see, so I'm not sure it's possible the way you're asking.

A possible workaround, however, would be to create a normal Excel file (.xls/.xlsx) in the various folders that is essentially the same 'template' document.  Then mark the file as Read Only in the operating system (right-click, properties, read-only).

When Excel opens a read-only file it will not let you save it over the original, so when you attempt to save it, **you will be prompted for a new name and Excel will default to the folder you opened the document from**.

If you want to get fancier, you could have a `Workbook.Open` event triggered that checks if `ActiveWorkbook.ReadOnly` is `True`, then prompt for a file name and save the file.